# Best jQuery plugin implementation for binding JavaScript's oninput event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I know jQuery doesn't support the oninput event, so have myself started to write a plugin to do the job. Although don't understanding very well all the stuff related to events in jQuery or JavaScript I ended up with usable code that currently satisfies my requirements.

Unfortunately I think my current implementation can crash, specially when using it in conjunction with other libraries because am setting directly the oninput member of the DOM elements.

Do you know a better and portable way to solve this problem, maybe using methods such as jQuery's "on" or JavaScript "addEventListener"?

Here is a working example of the code i'm currently using:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// jQuery plugin to bind an event handler to the "oninput" JavaScript event.
(function ($) {

   // Add an "input" method to all jQuery objects
   $.fn.input = function (handler) {

      // iterate over all DOM elements in the jQuery object
      this.each( function () {
         // set a new method to run when "oninput" is fired
         this.oninput = function (prevHandler) {
            return function (ev) {
               // call previous handler if exists
               if( typeof prevHandler === 'function' ) {
                  prevHandler.call (this, ev);
               }
               // call new handler
               handler.call (this, ev);
            };
         }(this.oninput);  // immediate evaluation, pass current handler as argument
      });
   };
} (jQuery));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Test the plugin
$(document).ready (function () {
   $('#one').input (function () {
      alert ('Input on one: ' + $(this).val());
   });
   $('#three,#four').input (function () {
      alert ('Input on three or four: ' + $(this).val());
   });
   $('#one,#two,#three').input (function () {
      alert ('Input on one, two, or three: ' + $(this).val());
   });
   $('#one,#two,#three,#four').input (function () {
      alert ('Input on any: ' + $(this).val());
   });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input id='one'/><br/>
<input id='two'/><br/>
<input id='three'/><br/>
<input id='four'/><br/>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's 'on' can handle any event so you could simply do something like this:

```
(function() {
    var outputElement = document.getElementById('mirror-input');
    $('#input-stuff').on('input', function (event) {
        outputElement.innerText = event.target.value; 
    });
}())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YCAtZ/

Comment: Not if said browser doesn't support the input event, though the given plugin doesn't seem to provide that support either.